# Refresh variable after update

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to find a way to refresh the count on a class after a successfull mysql update. At the moment I am using a class to display the information and for styling and this works well on page load. Is is possible to refresh a class after update. `$ni;` stores the result after mysql count.

I have attached the code I am using and would be grateful for any advice. Thanks

**html**

```
<ul>
    <li>
      <a href="/domain/admin/test.php" title="Add">New Intake <span class="notification" style="float: right;"><?php echo $ni; ?></span></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**php**

```
<?php    
  $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT count(*) as total FROM act WHERE new = '1'"); // provide db connection object as first parameter
  $rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
  $num = $rows['total'];
  $ni = $num;

  if ($ni < 1) {
    $ni = '0';    
  }
?>
```

Comment: You could do this by sending a request to run the PHP via AJAX then update the DOM using the AJAX callback method

Comment: @MasterYoda do you have example please. Just a starter would do. Would I do this within success call? Run another ajax. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make an AJAX call after you execute the SQL update in order to obtain the latest data and insert it in the DOM as mentioned by [Master Yoda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2500842/master-yoda) in the comments.

**Example ajax code:**

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'yourURL',
        success: function(msg){
            $(".notification").text(msg);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus)
        {
            //Manage your error.   
        }
    });
```

**Explanation**: 'yourURL' should be replaced with a link to the php page that calculates the value and returns it. On success that value will be written in the `span` with class `notification`. Also you need to execute the ajax code every time you do an updated.

More information about [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp)

Comment: Thanks very much for starter. Got it working this way: `$.get('/ldomain/admin/requests/boxes/retrieve/refreshBox.php?rtvni=' + 'New Intake', function(data) {
          console.log(data);
          $(".notification").text(data); });`